# If $m,n\in \mathbb N$ and $n>m$, prove that $\text{lcm}(m,n)+\text{lcm}(m+1,n+1)>\frac{2mn}{\sqrt{n-m}}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisibility

Where $\text{lcm}$ is the least common multiple.

I've changed it to: $$\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}+\frac{(m+1)(n+1)}{\gcd(m+1,n+1)}>\frac{2mn}{\sqrt{n-m}}$$ Can't see how to continue.

Is there a way to evaluate $\gcd(m,n)\gcd(m+1,n+1)$? To make it equal to another $\gcd$ or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $n>m$. Then  $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd\left(m,n-m\right)$ and $\gcd\left(m+1,n+1\right)=\gcd(m+1,n-m)$. Now, since $\gcd(m+1,m)=1$, it follows that $$n-m\geq\gcd\left(m(m+1),n-m\right)=\gcd(m,n-m)\cdot\gcd(m+1,n-m).$$ Applying the AM-GM  inequality we have $$\frac{1}{\gcd(m,n)}+\frac{1}{\gcd\left(m+1,n+1\right)}\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt{\gcd(m,n-m)\gcd(m+1,n-m)}}\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-m}},$$ and since $(m+1)(n+1)>mn$, by multiplying both sides by $mn$ we conclude that $$\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}+\frac{(m+1)(n+1)}{\gcd\left(m+1,n+1\right)}>\frac{2mn}{\sqrt{n-m}}.$$

Comment: You don't need to "suppose that $n>m$". It's already given.

Comment: @mathh: I decided to restate what we are assuming at the start of the proof so that it would be self contained, and make sense even if the question were removed or altered significantly.

Comment: What follows from $\gcd(m+1,m)=1$? That $\gcd(m+1,n-m)=\gcd(m(m+1),n-m)$?

Comment: @Mathh: Since $\gcd(m,m+1)=1$, we have that $\gcd(m(m+1),n-m)=\gcd(m,n-m)\cdot\gcd(m+1,n-m)$. In other words, because $m$ and $m+1$ are relatively prime, the primes powers which divide both $m(m+1)$ and $n-m$ can be split into those primes powers which divide both $n-m$ and $m$, as well as those primes powers which divide both $n-m$ and $m+1$.

Comment: That's exactly the equality that I've shown in the description of the question. $\gcd(xy,z)=\gcd(x,z)\gcd(y,z)$. It seems like you're implying that this is only true when $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Comment: @Mathh: Without the $\gcd(x,y)=1$ condition, it is not true in general. For example, let $z=4$, $x=2$ and $y=4$. Then $\gcd(xy,z)=4$, yet $\gcd(x,z)\gcd(y,z)=2\cdot 4=8$.