# Prove for $m,\ n$ $\in \Bbb N$ and $m > n$ we have : $\text{lcm}(m,n)+\text{lcm}(m+1,n+1)>\frac{2mn}{\sqrt{m-n}}$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'll show lcm $(a,b)$ by $[a,b]$ and $\gcd(a,b)$ by $(a,b) $.

$$[m,n]+[m+1,n+1]>\frac{2mn}{\sqrt{n-m}}
$$

This is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
m-n&\ge (m,n)\\
\implies [m,n]&\ge\frac{mn}{m-n}
\end{align*}

so we have :

\begin{align*}
[m,n]+[m+1,n+1]&\ge\frac{mn+(m+1)(n+1)}{m-n}\\
&=\frac{2mn}{m-n}+\frac{m+n+1}{m-n}
\end{align*}

and here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hi everyone. There is the same question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/615861/1068617 but there was only one answer that was wrong you can see at above link. or at least I think it's wrong :)

Comment: The answer by Eric is not wrong. You need to apply the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is this true? $\gcd(m(m+1),n-m)=\gcd(m,n-m)\cdot\gcd(m+1,n-m)$ this is true as long as all the GCDs is equal to 1.

Comment: $m$ and $m+1$ are coprime, and $n>m$ by assumption (you have $\sqrt{n-m}$, so $m>n$ is not correct in your title.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited title. And could you generally say when $\gcd(a,bc)=\gcd(a,b)\cdot\gcd(a,c)$ holds ?